# 'delete from' query problem

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I created the following two table

```
create table mail(mid integer primary key, name varchar(20) )
create table phone( pid integer foreign key references mail(email), phone integer)
```

'delete record of pid=12'. that means, i have to delete record of pid=12 from oth table. so, i ran following query.

```
delete from mail, phone on mail.mid=phone.pid where pid=12
```

but i got the error like 'check the syntax near from', what to do then to get the proper output.

Thanks & regards,
Pooja.

Answer (score 4):

You have to perform the two operations separately. Wrap them in a transaction to make sure you maintain integrity in case something fails

```
declare @id int;
set @id = 12;

begin transaction 

    delete from mail where pid = @id;
    if @@error = 0 
        delete from phone where pid = @id;
    else
        rollback transaction;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just let the database handle it by using a CASCADING DELETE on your foreign key.

Comment: will you plz tell, how can use that 'CASCADING DELETE'? bcuz, i heard it for the first time.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but the db user account needs to have the rights to `Alter Table`

Comment: @Pooja A cascading delete is a master-detail (foreign key) relation where the details are automatically deleted when the master is deleted. What RBDMS are you using? Microsoft SQL Server? In that case have a look at http://rudesyle.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/cascading-deletes-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

if you're working with oracle you can use `ON DELETE CASCADE` when creating a table option

```
create table phone( pid integer , phone integer, foreign key(pid) REFERENCES mail ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two queries.

> delete from mail where pid = 12;
>   delete from phone where pid = 12;

Comment: Sorry, its not working. It shows the error like "check syntax near ',' "

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be `... where phone.pid=12`

Answer (score 0):

The use of the keyword ON is not valid in that position, if you want to inner-join on that condition, move it to the where clause

```
delete from mail, phone where pid=12 AND mail.mid=phone.pid
```

Comment: Sorry, its not working. It shows the error like "check syntax near ',' "

Answer (score 0):

If using mysql this is the syntax:

```
delete mail, phone 
from mail inner join phone 
where mail.mid=phone.pid and pid=12
```

Comment: Sorry, its not working. It shows the error like "check syntax near ',' "